# Android video always horizontal

Tags: android, android-camera

We have built our own Camera Preview and it fulfilled our initial expectations. However, I was looking into the possibility of having our Camera Preview capturing video frames in the same orientation (landscape) regardless of the phone orientation. With these feature, it wouldn't matter how the user holds the phone since it will always capture the video frames in the same orientation.

The images are currently captured in one orientation but if the user rotates the phone, the images will look rotated as the phone rotates. How can I capture the part of the screen that matches the desired orientation like in [Google Play Store app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cmdd.horicam&hl=en)?

```
@Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera cam) {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(_prevTime + DELAY_MS > currentTime){
            return;             
        }
        _prevTime = currentTime;
        Camera.Parameters params = cam.getParameters();
        Size size = params.getPreviewSize();
        YuvImage image = new YuvImage(bytes, ImageFormat.NV21, size.width,
                size.height, null);
        Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,size.width,size.height);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int qual = params.getJpegQuality();
        image.compressToJpeg(rect, params.getJpegQuality(), byteStream);
        try{
            File pictureFile = getOutputFile();
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            output.write(byteStream.toByteArray());
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            Log.e("ShareHim", "File not found");
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e("ShareHim", "IO exception");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a TextureView instead a SurfaceView? TextureView allows you to add a transformation Matrix to rotate the image after capturing it.

Comment: I am using a SurfaceView. Now, If I use a TextureView can I change the way I capture the image? (e.g., to emulate something like what this app does [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cmdd.horicam&hl=en))

Comment: Yes, as you can rotate, scale, skew, etc via transformation matrix. About horizontal pictures in portrait mode, I guess it's using some cropping tricks